# cannot get mongod to start first time

Tags: mongodb

I've downloaded mongodb for windows on windows 7 home.  I've followed the instructions given on the website.  I'm using directory c:\mongo, with c:\data.  When I try to start mongod.exe with or without admin status I get the same popup window: "mongod.exe has stopped working".  This does not seem to be an issue which appears much on the 'net but as an occasional windows user I'm lost (failed on SuSE13.2 as well with a FIPS problem).  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I know little of Windows, though I would guess mongodb should launched as a Service, not to be launched by double clicking ... How is mongodb getting launched ?

Comment: I tried double clicking, and also by running it with admin features.  As I say, windows is largely a closed book to me (mainly linux for 10 years), so I'm not sure how to run something as a service.  I'll try to figure it out.  Incidentally I've just got it running on Gentoo - which has other issues.